# PHP - compare day and time to array / database (not literal dates)

Tags: php

I'll start by saying i'm not a programmer. Like a lot of people I can hack something together from examples in PHP, JS, PowerShell etc but I'm throwing a blank here.

I'm trying to create a page which will show what the current daily mission is in Everquest 2. These missions change every 18 hours and are recurring at the same day/time every week.

The below works but it's... awful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$h = date('G'); //set variable $h to the server hour of the day, "G" is the date key for hours in 24 format (not 12), with no leading 0s, like 02. Adjust hourly offset in the event of daylight savings problems.. i.e $h = $h-2;
$h = $h+7;
$d = date('w'); //set variable $d to the server day of the week, 0=Sunday, 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday, 3=Wednesday, 4=Thursday, 5=Friday, 6=Saturday

// Monday before 1400
if ($d == 1 && $h < 14) $text = 'Ossuary: Sanguine Fountains [Heroic]';

// Monday after 1400
if ($d == 1 && $h >= 14) $text = 'Ossuary: Resonance of Malice [Heroic]';

// Tuesday before 0800
if ($d == 2 && $h < 8) $text = 'Ossuary: Resonance of Malice [Heroic]';
// Tuesday after 0800
if ($d == 2 && $h >= 8) $text = 'Ssraeshza Temple [Heroic]';

// Wednesday before 0200
if ($d == 3 && $h < 2) $text = 'Ssraeshza Temple [Heroic]';
// Wednesday after 0200 but before 2000
if ($d == 3 && $h >= 2 && $H < 20) $text = 'Ssraeshza Temple: Inner Sanctum [Heroic]';
// Wednesday after 2000
if ($d == 3 && $h >= 20) $text = 'Brokenskull Bay: Bilgewater Falls [Heroic]';

// Thursday before 1400
if ($d == 4 && $h < 14) $text = 'Brokenskull Bay: Bilgewater Falls    [Heroic]';
// Thursday after 1400
if ($d == 4 && $h >= 14) $text = 'Brokenskull Bay: Hoist the Yellow Jack [Heroic]';

// Friday before 0800
if ($d == 5 && $h < 8) $text = 'Brokenskull Bay: Hoist the Yellow Jack [Heroic]';
// Friday after 0800
if ($d == 5 && $h >= 8) $text = 'Zavithloa: The Lost Caverns [Heroic]';

// Saturday before 0200
if ($d == 6 && $h < 2) $text = 'Zavithloa: The Lost Caverns [Heroic]';
// Saturday after 0200 but before 2000
if ($d == 6 && $h >= 2 && $H < 20) $text = 'Zavithloa: The Hidden Caldera [Heroic]';
// Saturday after 2000
if ($d == 6 && $h >= 20) $text = 'Castle Highhold [Heroic]';

// Sunday before 0200
if ($d == 0 && $h < 2) $text = 'Castle Highhold [Heroic]';
// Sunday after 0200 but before 2000
if ($d == 0 && $h >= 2 && $H < 20) $text = 'Castle Highhold: Thresinets Den [Heroic]';
// Sunday after 2000
if ($d == 0 && $h >= 20) $text = 'Ossuary: Sanguine Fountains [Heroic]';

echo "Current Daily Mission: $text <BR>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If it was a date, I'd probably put it in an SQL table and then loop through to do a datediff but I'm not sure how to work with it in the current format.. I'd also prefer to put it in an array and loop through that but again, not sure the best way to work with it.. should I use the Mission name as the key and then find a way to separate the start and end time? But due to the arbitrary way I'm storing the information I'm not sure how to compare against a day/time?

```
$MissionTimes = array(
0 => "Mission1:1-14-00:2-8-00",
1 => "Mission2:2-8-00:3-2-00",
2 => "Mission3:3-2-00:3-20-00",
3 => "Mission4:3-20-00:4-14-00",
4 => "Mission5:4-14-00:5-8-00",
5 => "Mission6:5-8-00:6-2-00",
6 => "Mission7:6-2-00:6-18-00",
7 => "Mission8:6-18-00:0-2-00",
8 => "Mission9:0-2-00:0-18-00",
9 => "Mission10:0-18-00:1-14-00",
);
```

Any help pointers/suggestions would be really appreciated.

EDIT....
With Everts help, I now have an array and a loop function that works, could anyone help me with how to get the "next" result as well as the final? The only way I could think to do it is to add the end-time too, then use a for loop to check if the current day/time is between the current foreach day/time but this would fall apart when a mission falls between Saturday (day 6) and Sunday (day 0).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Daily "start" time listed below in GMT, each daily lasts 18 hours.

// Sunday (0) 2AM = Castle Highhold: Thresinet’s Den [Heroic]
// Sunday (0) 8PM = Ossuary: Sanguine Fountains [Heroic]
// Monday (1) 2PM = Ossuary: Resonance of Malice [Heroic]
// Tuesday (2) 8AM = Ssraeshza Temple [Heroic]
// Wednesday (3) 2AM = Ssraeshza Temple: Inner Sanctum [Heroic]
// Wednesday (3) 8PM = Brokenskull Bay: Bilgewater Falls [Heroic]
// Thursday (4) 2PM = Brokenskull Bay: Hoist the Yellow Jack [Heroic]
// Friday (5) 8AM = Zavith’loa: The Lost Caverns [Heroic]
// Saturday (6) 2AM = Zavith’loa: The Hidden Caldera [Heroic]
// Saturday (6) 8PM = Castle Highhold [Heroic]

$MissionTimes = array(
array( 
      'missionid' => "Castle Highhold: Thresinet’s Den [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 0,
      'starthour' => 0
     ),
array( 
      'missionid' => "Castle Highhold: Thresinet’s Den [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 0,
      'starthour' => 2
     ),
array( 
      'missionid' => "Ossuary: Sanguine Fountains [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 0,
      'starthour' => 20
     ),
array(
      'missionid' => "Ossuary: Resonance of Malice [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 1,
      'starthour' => 14
     ),
array( 
      'missionid' => "Ssraeshza Temple [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 2,
      'starthour' => 8
     ),
array( 
      'missionid' => "Ssraeshza Temple: Inner Sanctum [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 3,
      'starthour' => 2
     ),
array( 
      'missionid' => "Brokenskull Bay: Bilgewater Falls [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 3,
      'starthour' => 20
     ),
array( 
      'missionid' => "Brokenskull Bay: Hoist the Yellow Jack [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 4,
      'starthour' => 14
     ),
array( 
      'missionid' => "Zavith’loa: The Lost Caverns [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 5,
      'starthour' => 8
     ),
array( 
      'missionid' => "Zavith’loa: The Hidden Caldera [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 6,
      'starthour' => 2
     ),
array( 
      'missionid' => "Castle Highhold [Heroic]",
      'startdow'  => 6,
      'starthour' => 20
     )
);

$hour = date('G');
$dow = date('w');
$hour = $hour+7;

foreach($MissionTimes as $mission)
{
   if ($mission['startdow'] > $dow)
   {
     // If the current date of the week is higher than the start dow of
     // of this mission, we skip to the next item.
    continue;
   }
   if ($mission['starthour'] > $hour)
   {
     // If the current hour of the day is higher than the start hour of
     // of this mission, we skip to the next item.
    continue;
   }

   $missionstring = $mission['missionid'];
// break;
}

echo "The current mission is: $missionstring";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're pretty close, but I would change the structure a bit to not pack everything into a single string.

Example:

```
$MissionTimes = [
  [
    'missionid' => 1,
    'startdow'  => 1,
    'starthour' => 14  
  ],
  [
    'missionid' => 1,
    'startdow'  => 1,
    'starthour' => 14  
  ],
  [
    'missionid' => 2,
    'startdow'  => 2,
    'starthour' => 8  
  ],
  /*** etc ***/
];
```

So a few notes:

1. I split up all your values into 3 different ones.
2. I removed the 'end date of the week' and 'end time', because as far as I can see it always is identical to the starttime of the next mission, so we don't need it twice.
3. `[ and ]` is identical to `array( and )`.

So how would you find the current mission?

```
$hour = date('G');
$dow = date('w');

$missionId = 0;

foreach($MissionTimes as $mission) {
    if ($mission['startdow']) > $dow) {
       // If the current date of the week is higher than the start dow of
       // of this mission, we skip to the next item.
       continue; 
    }
    if ($mission['starthour'] > $hour) {
       // If the current hour of the day is higher than the start hour of
       // of this mission, we skip to the next item.
       continue;
    }

    // If we got here, stop the loop.
    $missionId = $mission['missionid'];
    break;
}
```

2 more notes:

1. I didn't test this code.
2. You need to make absolute sure that your `$MissionTimes` array is in order, and starts with an entry that starts at midnight on sunday (hour 0, day 0).

Lastly, you didn't mention anything about timezones, but you add 7 hours to the hour value... this is weird. My assumption is that the everquest mission times are in UTC and you're in pacific time. To get the values for UTC instead, use the `gmdate()` instead of the `date()` function.

Comment: This worked a treat but I had to remove the break and for some reason it didn't like the formatting of your array, once i understood what it was (a multidimensional array) I did a little search. Now all I have to do is figure out how to determine what the next mission will be.

I'm adding 7 hours to the value because I only know the GMT times for the changes and I can't remember what time zone the server is in, when I find it, I'll change the times as appropriate and remove the hour modifier.

Comment: See my last comment. Use `gmdate()` instead of blindly adding hours (which will not work after the DST change anyway). Also, the array issue is probably because you're using an outdated PHP version.

Comment: this wouldn't surprise me. I'm using Bluehosts as I've just started dabbling with Wordpress. Judging by phpinfo() it's PHP Version 5.2.17 - thanks again for all your help. Happy to have a working solution.

Comment: PHP 5.2 is really really old... get a new host, it might not seem like it now, but you will run into issues with a host that clearly does not care.

Comment: in all fairness, I hadn't properly investigated anything short of what version was installed. Just checked the cpanel and switching to 5.4 was just a toggle.. not sure why it defaulted to 5.2 but /shrug - just wanted to comment in case anyone else saw.

Comment: 5.4 is also _almost_ end of life. 5.6 or bust.